# Working with links to non-existing files

Tags: bash

I'm new to BASH and I'm trying to create a script that would work with links to non-existing. Script may have several parameters, which are link to directory, "-v" -- script will output 1, "-r" -- script will remove links to all non-existing files, "-a" -- script will output links to all files in the directory. There can be several parameters in any order. This is what I came up with :

```
#!/bin/bash

linkchk_r () {
    for element in $1/*; do
        [ -h "$element" -a ! -e "$element" ] && $ rm "$element"
    done
}

linkchk_a (){
    for element in $1/*; do
        echo "$element"
    done
}

if [ $1 = "-v" ]
then
    echo 1
fi

case "$3" in
"-a" )
    linkchk_a $2
;;

"-r" )
    linkchk_r $2
;;

esac

exit 0
```

But the testing system says the script works for more than 1 minute, so I've got a mistake somewhere. Can you please help me find it and give advice on the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

if `stat softlink` works Ok, but `stat -L softlink` returns a non-zero status, it;s a dangling link. Check [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) manpage